# The best way to convert Array<Int32> to Array<Int> in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, casting

I have `Array<Int32>` with large size and I want to convert it into `Array<Int>`.

Then, I am using `map` function like this;

```swift
let int32array = Array<Int32>(0..<1000000)

let intarray = int32array.map{ Int($0) }
```

However, I think this method may not be efficient because this method does conversion for each value. I want to use the function like [vDSP](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vdsp/type_conversion?language=objc) to convert Array type at once.

Is there the best efficient way? or is this method the best efficient?

**Benchmark**

- `map` method

```swift
let a = Array<Int32>(0..<1000000)
self.measure{
    let _ = a.map{ Int($0) }
}
```

```
average: 0.003, relative standard deviation: 24.146%, values: [0.004856, 0.003898, 0.003299, 0.002819, 0.002803, 0.002510, 0.002768, 0.002651, 0.002425, 0.002466]
```

- `NSNumber` method

```swift
let a = Array<Int32>(0..<1000000)
self.measure{
    let _ = a as [NSNumber] as! [Int]
}
```

```
average: 0.107, relative standard deviation: 21.407%, values: [0.174483, 0.108488, 0.108955, 0.096895, 0.095688, 0.095913, 0.095392, 0.098701, 0.098499, 0.098477],
```

Comment: Does the situation allow to do it lazily?

Comment: Yes. But I want converted array by the best efficient way if I could because real-time calculating is important in my app

Comment: `let integers = int32array as [NSNumber] as! [Int]`

Comment: @Leo Thanks! I’ll check it later. Is this conversion always success in both 32bit and 64bit architecture?

Comment: @LeoDabus: I wonder if that is really more efficient, it creates many NSNumber instances and an intermediate array.

Comment: @jjjkkkjjj: Did you benchmark your code? How long does the conversion with `map` take? Is that a performance bottleneck in your program?

Comment: In a simple benchmark, using `NSNumber` is about 20 times slower than using `map`, as expected.

Comment: @LeoDabus: I checked `NSNumber` method. Unfortunately, `NSNumber` method is slower than `map`. See updated question again.

Comment: @jjjkkkjjj, you should better test two cases under Optimized build.

Comment: @MartinR: I want to purely know how conversion method is the best efficient.